# Problema ao seguir o tutorial sobre o WinUSB do MSDN, da Microsoft

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, usb

Tenho encontrado problemas em seguir o tutorial da MSDN Microsoft sobre WinUSB. O tutorial é [Write a Windows desktop app based on the WinUSB template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn376872(v=vs.85).aspx).

Seguindo as instruções, na etapa em que preciso criar uma aplicação WinUSB o site diz que **dois projetos** irão ser criados, porém, minha aplicação apenas cria **um projeto**.

Estou utilizando **Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015** e instalei **WDK**. **Nota:** *Estou utilizando Windows 10 64 bits.*

Abaixo segue parte do tutorial dizendo que **dois projetos** irão ser criados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo segue um *screenshot* da minha *Solution Explorer*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender o porque isto está acontecendo e ajudar a resolver esta questão?

Comment: Só questão de curiosidade, que tipo de dispositivo está usando neste projeto?

Comment: Estou utilizando um sensor de biometria, preciso criar uma aplicação que realize a leitura de digitais através desse dispositivo usb

Comment: C++ é pré-requisito ou é questão de estudo, etc?

Comment: Foi pré-requisito por causa do tutorial. Minha intenção é conseguir acessar os dados da digital pela USB por qualquer linguagem, desde que em consiga. A manipulação dos dados da digital pretendo utilizar `java`

Comment: O dispositivo não fornece nenhuma dll/framework/sdk?